# Write response from multiple data JSON Array

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

As an example, if I type `sicans`, I have a response from the API like this:

```js
{
  "data": {
    "Data1": [{
      "name": "sicans",
      "phone_number": "01234",
      "email": "i@a.a",
      "status": "ACTIVE",
    }],
    "Data2": [],
    "Data3": [],
    "Data4": []
  }
}
```

I need to capture the data and then write the response. I have tried `console.log` like below, but the it is empty. Do you know how I can get `name` response from the response?

```js
$.ajax({
  url: api_url + 'search?keyword=' + pencarian,
  type: 'GET',
  success: function(response) {
    for (var i = 0; i < response.data.length; i++) {
      var name = response.data[i].Data1.name;
      console.log(name)
    }
  }
})
```

Thank you

Comment: response.data.Data1.length

Comment: Do you control the API at all? If so you should really change the format of the response to be something which is more suitable to work with.

Comment: Your array/object access is mixed up. Try `var name = response.data.Data1[0].name;`

Comment: Try console.log(response) and move from there

Comment: to get a response structute use JSON.stringify(response)

Comment: @Raphael even aside from having that backwards, you want `JSON.parse()` to get the response from JSON, it's not relevant to the problem; if the response hadn't already been parsed there would be an error to do with accessing an undefined value by index.

Comment: Hi @EugeneSunic, I have tried but it's error message `Cannot read property 'length' of undefined`

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this, you need to apply length on the array not on object

```
  success: function(response) {
    let array = response.data.Data1
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
      var name = array[i].name;
      console.log(name)
    }
  }
```

Comment: Hi Eugene, it's showing `Cannot read property 'length' of undefined` when I tried

Answer (score 0):

`response.data` is of type `Object`. So if you write `response.data[i]`, it returns undefined since `response.data` has no integer keys.

```js
var response = {
  "data": {
    "Data1": [{
      "name": "sicans",
      "phone_number": "01234",
      "email": "i@a.a",
      "status": "ACTIVE",
    }],
    "Data2": [{
      "name": "sicans2",
      "phone_number": "01234",
      "email": "i@a.a",
      "status": "ACTIVE",
    }],
    "Data3": [{
      "name": "sicans3",
      "phone_number": "01234",
      "email": "i@a.a",
      "status": "ACTIVE",
    }],
    "Data4": [{
      "name": "sicans4",
      "phone_number": "01234",
      "email": "i@a.a",
      "status": "ACTIVE",
    }]
  }
}

//Trying to access with integer key. Will return "undefined"
console.log(response.data[0]);


// This example is using "Object.keys()" 
console.log('With Object.keys()');
Object.keys(response.data).forEach((key) => {
  var name = response.data[key][0].name;
  //                           ^^ this is here because Data1, Data2 etc. are of type Array. We need to get first element
  console.log(key, name)
});


// This example is using "Object.values()" 
console.log('With Object.values()');
Object.values(response.data).forEach((data) => {
  var name = data[0].name;
  //             ^^ this is here because Data1, Data2 etc. are of type Array. We need to get first element
  console.log(name)
});
```

Comment: Thanks Harun, now I know why `Cannot read property 'length' of undefined` happens in my code

Answer (score 0):

If you need to loop from Data1 to Data4 I, what you are looking for is [Object.keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)

```js
var response = {
  "data": {
    "Data1": [{
      "name": "sicans",
      "phone_number": "01234",
      "email": "i@a.a",
      "status": "ACTIVE",
    }],
    "Data2": [],
    "Data3": [],
    "Data4": []
  }
}

var keys = Object.keys(response.data);
for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
  var data = response.data[keys[i]]
  for (var j = 0; j < data.length; j++) {
    var name = data[j].name;
    console.log(name);
  }
}
```

Otherwise like Eugene Sunic pointed out, you can change the original loop to the following:

```js
 var response = {
      "data": {
        "Data1": [{
          "name": "sicans",
          "phone_number": "01234",
          "email": "i@a.a",
          "status": "ACTIVE",
        }],
        "Data2": [],
        "Data3": [],
        "Data4": []
      }
    }

for (var i = 0; i < response.data.Data1.length; i++) {
  var name = response.data.Data1[i].name;
  console.log(name);
}
```

Let me know if it helps.

Comment: Hi Eric, I have tried your first suggestons, and it's work for me.

Comment: I have tried what Eugene Sunic pointed out, but it's showing error message `Cannot read property 'length' of undefined`

Comment: Glad to see it works for you.  The second snippet is the full code that Eugene suggested.  By looking at the error message I suppose you did not change the following line: var name = response.data.Data1[i].name;

Comment: Hi Eric, how I know if I have same variable name in other data, like in `Data2` or `Data3` I have variable data named `name` too, there's the right data that I want ?

Comment: I am not sure I understand correctly but I wrote the snippet without knowing what would be the content of Data2...4.  My expectation was that it was the same as Data1.  I have no clue as what kind of API you were calling in your provided example.  What you should do is to look into the API's documentation to know what is the format of Data2...4